# VIM: Yank multiple non-continous chunks of text into a registers

Tags: vim, regex

I have some lines of text that follow a pattern and some that don't. I'd like to copy the lines that follow this pattern and then copy/yank them into a register so that I can paste them as is someplace else.

Example:

```
def function_1(param1,param2):
    // do something1
    // do something2
    // do something3
    return

def function_Nullify(param=None):
    // does nothing
    pass
```

Now I'd basically like to select the lines that match `def.*$`, copy them and paste them.

so the output would kindof look like this:

```
def function_1(param1,param2):
def function_Nullify(param=None):
```

I want to know if it's possible to do this in vim.

Something like copy matched regex lines into register "m. Then I'd be able to do a "mp where ever else I need this.

---

I understand that something like sed, awk or grep with some redirection operators might be better suited to this task, but I'd like to know if I can use vim to do this.

Comment: If you want to index your code, you might be interested in [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) or [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I didn't know about these. Thanks! ctags seems like it'll help a lot.

Comment: Random downvoter, please explain your downvote alteast?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `"Myy` (capital letter M) to append into register m. This allows you write a global command to yank all lines matching `def.*$` and yank all the lines into the m register. Then all you have to do is paste the m register to get the contents `"mp`

```
:g/def.*$/normal "Myy
```

The above global command tell you to find all lines that match the pattern `def.*$` and execute the command `"Myy` in normal mode.

However this has one problem. What happens if the m register is not empty when you start. Well you will end up with what ever you put into the register last time plus all the stuff you appended.

To empty the register you can use to set the register to the empty string.

```
:let @m=''
```

So in vim you would type

```
:let @m=''
:g/def.*$/normal "Myy
```

To yank everything that matches `def.*$` into the m register.

Comment: A shorter alternative: `:g/def.*$/y M`.

Comment: How do I yank a particular submatch? Say I want just function names and have the following pattern that puts them into `\1`: `def\ \([^(]*\).*$`. How to modify the `:g...` command to yank `\1` rather than the full match?

Comment: @taketwo the `submatch()` function seems like it might help you in what you're trying to do. I haven't been able to use it properly yet though.

Comment: @romainl I didn't know you could use `y` after a g... command. Thanks!

Comment: @taketwo, unfortunately you can't reuse capture groups from the `:g` command. What you ask could be done with a combination of `:global` and a macro, though.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions! that was actually a pure curiosity, never found myself in a need to do something like this.